# Intellij: "Error running Scala Console: Cannot Start Process"

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, configuration

New install.

Scala SBT project.

Full message is:

> Error running Scala Console: Cannot start process, the working
>   directory C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community
>   Edition 13.1.4\jre\jre\bin does not exist

It would be nice to have the directory default to somewhere sensible in the current project...I think.

Comment: Sounds like the Intellij JDK/JRE config points wrong to me? If you look at module settings, does the JDK config show a warning/red maybe?

Comment: @johanandren It's in the `working directory` setting for the Run/Debug config. See my answer below. I'm not sure if I'm actually pointing at the current directory with ` . `, but I can get it to run.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. From the application menu, selecting `Run -> Edit Configurations` opens the `Run/Debug Configurations` dialog.
2. In the left panel of the dialog, pick `Defaults -> Scala Console`.
3. In the `Working Directory` textbox, enter `.`.

It would be great to set this as a default, because the tests also require the same manual settings.

Answer (score 0):

Happen to me due to a bug in BSP, I used an older version and solved it.

Also - I looked for more details in the idea log (To open it go to File Menu -> Help -> Show Log in Finder) and noticed some plugin was throwing an error and caused this issue (kator), after disabling the plugin and restarting the idea things went back to normal