# Error: "Cannot start process, the working directory does not exist." in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When I move a whole project from one computer to another, and I try to start the project in IDEA on the other computer, the following error occurred when I start my application itself: "Cannot start process, the working directory does not exist."

There's no context for me to put this message in. I checked all my settings and everything seems to be all right. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Check the `idea.log` for possible hints (`Help | Show Log in XXX`)

Comment: I'm willing to bet that you copied over things like the .idea folder and various IDE-centric files.  If you purge those configs and recreate your project from scratch, do you still get the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For IntelliJ all I had to do was create a directory called `modules` in the project's `.idea` folder. This solved the issue. But my specific error said `the working directory does not exist` and it had my project path and ended in `project/.idea/modules`.

Note that doing `rm -r .idea/` in the project folder did not solve my issue.

Comment: weird that creating an empty folder fixed this... thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issues which has been fixed and working fine.

Solution: Go to FOlder where your project resides. Search for ".idea" folder --> delete that folder and then open the code and go to "settings.gradle(Project Setting)" file -- >

cut the line "include ':app'" -- > Sync Now --> now paste the same "include ':app'" and Sync now again --> Issues resolved -- > Last Clean & Revuild the project

Answer (score 2):

See here : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25922840/5334435

You need to set a value "." for the working directory. And remember to set it as Default, in order no to reset it every time.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate Caches / Restart Worked in my case